# Bootstrap material design input field doesn't animate

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I am using Material Design for Bootstrap 3: http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/

So far, I only have the navbar and it looks good but the "Search" input field doesn't animate when I click inside it.

Nor does it give me the splash effect when I click on the dropdown menu.

Any idea what I'm missing?

```
<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/ripples.min.css') }}">

<body id="app-layout">
<div class="bs-component">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('home') }}">APP</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
                            <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/profile/settings') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-cog"></i>Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/profile/password') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-cog"></i>Change Password</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@yield('content')

<!-- JavaScripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/ripples.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/material.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ripples CSS and JS are missing, this is why you aren't seeing the "ripple" animation on your click events.

Docs: [Getting Started](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#getting-started)

Working Example:

```js
$.material.init()
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.9/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.9/css/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.9/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.9/js/ripples.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">APP</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
            <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
      </form>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            NAME <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-cog"></i> Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-cog"></i> Change Password</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```